# Listen to events in the browser scope - keyUp on browser app bar buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

I am wondering if there is a way to listen to events that are happening higher in the hierarchy than window or document. Currently I was listening to KeyUp (JavaScript):

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleWindowKeyup);
```

*handleWindowKeyup* is called whenever I press TAB key as long as I am navigating through elements on the page. When focus is moved to browser elements (e.g. search bar) my handler is not invoked until I am back to any element of the HTML page.

It makes sense as I registered handlers for the window object, but I am wondering if there is a way to listen to all events that are happening in the browser (not only page).

(Example) - when I press TAB and focus lands on search bar (padlock), *handleWindowKeyup* is not called.

[image]

Comment: So you writing an extension??

Comment: No, I have some code that is executed when I press TAB button and there are cases when it is not invoked because focus is moved out of my page.

Comment: There are no events for interacting with the browser